# I want Change requiresUniqueEmail error text in Literal createWizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Hi I want Change Text of error requiresUniqueEmail
i set requiresUniqueEmail provider to true
and massage default is The e-mail address that you entered is already in use. Please enter a different e-mail address
and i want change that text
my provide is

```
<add name="MemberShipProvider"
    type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
    connectionStringName="******"
    enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
    enablePasswordReset="true"
    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
    applicationName="/"
    requiresUniqueEmail="true"
    passwordFormat="Hashed"
    maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
    minRequiredPasswordLength="5"
    minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
    passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
    passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive this will work with SqlMembershipProvider but I've used this with the built-in sign up control:

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreateUserError(object sender, CreateUserErrorEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.CreateUserError)
    {
        case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
            RegisterUser.DuplicateUserNameErrorMessage = "No can do!";
            break;
        // other cases.
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```